# Image inside group not showing

Tags: javascript, image, kineticjs, image-resizing

I have a group into layer in Kineticjs with 4 circles as Anchor to resize the image. When click in a button create the image,group and anchors. 
The issue is when image and circles created the circles seems ok the image doesn't show until click over the area between four circles.

```
  var userGroup = new Kinetic.Group({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: width,
    height: height,
    draggable: true
  });

  var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

  var imageObj = new Image();

  var userImg = new Kinetic.Image({
    id : 'userimg',
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    image: imageObj,
    width: width,
    height: height,
    name: 'image'
  });

  userGroup.add(userImg);
  layer.add(userGroup);
  stage.add(layer);

  addAnchor(userGroup, 0, 0, 'topLeft');
  addAnchor(userGroup, width, 0, 'topRight');
  addAnchor(userGroup, width, height, 'bottomRight');
  addAnchor(userGroup, 0, height, 'bottomLeft');
  layer.draw();

  userGroup.on('dragstart', function() {
    layer.moveToTop();
    layer.draw();
  });    

  layer.draw();
  imageObj.src = uploadimg; // uploadimg = image url in my root web folder /images
  layer.draw();
  stage.draw();
});
```

Comment: It's a good practice to initialize the `Kinetic.image` in the `imageObj.onload` function. This way you create the `userImg` in the callback if the `imageObj` is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is your image isn't loaded yet. You are assigning it to a Kinetic.image and updating the layer before the image is even loaded. Therefore you need to add a callback to the onload function of the image.

You should do something like this:

```
imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.onload = function() {
    var userImg = new Kinetic.Image({
        id : 'userimg',
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        image: imageObj,
        width: width,
        height: height,
        name: 'image'
    });
    userGroup.add(userImg);
    layer.draw();
};
imageObj.src = uploadimg;
```

A good practice is load all images you need for your canvas before you even draw something on it. This snippet comes from [html5canvastutorials](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/):

```
function loadImages(sources, callback) {
    var images = {};
    var loadedImages = 0;
    var numImages = 0;
    for(var src in sources) {
        numImages++;
    }
    for(var src in sources) {
        images[src] = new Image();
        images[src].onload = function() {
            if(++loadedImages >= numImages) {
                callback(images);
            }
        };
        images[src].src = sources[src];
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var sources = {
    darthVader: 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg',
    yoda: 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/yoda.jpg'
};
loadImages(sources, function(images) {
    //all images are loaded in this callback function
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @A1rPun. I do it like your advice but now doesn't load the image at all. The problem with preloading is that in my senario a user choose photo from his FB profile and i don't know anything about the image until the click event happens.

Comment: @user3073773 what is `uploadimg` in your case? The image needs to be on its place when you define the `src` on the imageObj.

Comment: The user choose a photo then uploading a photo in my server and then i get my web server folder /images url in the uploadimg variable.

Comment: @nikoskor412 Hey you signed up ;) welcome! If you are sure the image is available at time of loading I don't see why he won't load it. Is the callback function even executed? I'm trying to reproduce your problem but my images are loading. Don't try the `loadImages` solution just yet, try the first snippet.

Comment: thenk you very much! I try the first snippet and it's ok. I had a mistake in onload with L instead of l and now fixed!